# Underscore methods on ruby model instance (ie: _validators)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What does the underscore / double underscore designate on instance methods in Rails?

For example if I have an instance of User and I tab the autocomplete I see the following:

[image: Autocomplete showing methods prepended with "_"]

I'm wondering what the "_" and "__" designate.

Comment: That its a method *private private* method. Like super super private. Its not a part of the API and should not be used outside of its original context. But its all just programmer convention - the interpreter doesn't care.

Comment: The convention is borrowed somewhat from Python and its lack of private properties and methods. But you'll also see it in other languages.

Comment: So safe to say I shouldn't be using any underscore or double underscore methods?

Comment: Yes, they could be moved/renamed/deleted at any time.